# Issue with using ShellWindows to find an open IE window

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I'm having an issue where intermittently this process will stop being able to locate an open IE window. As you can see, I debug the URL of every open window, so it's easy to see when a window simply isn't included in the list of objects that it loops through. Closing Excel and reopening it seems to resolve the issue, but I can't seem to find what causes it. Any ideas? Or alternatively, is there another process I could use to set an existing IE object by name or URL?

```vb
Public Function GetWindow(name As String)

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim l As Integer
    Dim TestStr As String
    Dim ShellW As ShellWindows

    Set ShellW = New ShellWindows
    On Error Resume Next
    If ShellW.Count > 0 Then
        For l = 0 To ShellW.Count - 1
            TestStr = ""
            TestStr = ShellW(l).LocationURL
            If TestStr <> "" Then
                Debug.Print TestStr
            End If
            If InStr(TestStr, name) > 0 Then
                If ShellW(l).Visible = True Then
                    If ie Is Nothing Then Set ie = ShellW(l): Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next l
    End If
    Set GetWindow = ie

End Function
```

Comment: Maybe comment out the `On Error Resume Next` and instead use a test to prevent whatever error you intended to suppress with it, then run again and see if anything else is erroring

Comment: E.g. test for  `ShellW(l).Name = "Internet Explorer"` before trying to check the `LocationURL`.  You don't need the `ie Is Nothing` test, because that will always be true.

Comment: True, I will try this the next time I can catch it mid-action, thanks.

Comment: In addition: `If ShellW.Count > 0 Then` and `TestStr = ""` lines are excessive, `ie` variable isn't necessary too, just declare `Function GetWindow() As InternetExplorer` and assign directly to it: `Set GetWindow = ShellW(l): Exit For`

Comment: `TestStr = ""` is useful (but not technically necessary) in this context: OERN will skip over `TestStr = ShellW(l).LocationURL` if it throws an error, leaving `TestStr` with the value from the previous iteration.